# Selenium Browser Absolute Location

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to get the absolute location of browser top left location.

In fact, the WebElement.getX() can only get the RELATIVE location with browser. So, does any one know how to get the browser's top left location, i.e. the beginning point of getX() method with Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

`driver.manage().window().getPosition()`

Comment: I thinks it's the API I'm looking for. Thanks!